# Thread names truncated - show full?

Tags: process, ps, htop

Seems like thread names get truncated everywhere (for example "IpcPipeBroadcas" instead of "IpcPipeBroadcas**t**". I've checked both htop and the below ps command. Is this hardcoded or is there any way to see the full names?

[image]

Comment: Sure. Lie to `ps` about your terminal width `COLUMNS=500 ps -T  p 1166`

Comment: @waltinator Sorry, that didn't work (same output). Interesting idea though.

Comment: iirc `ps` extends the final column to the full width if you specify columns explicitly ex. `ps -T -opid,spid,tname,time,cmd -p 1166` however the thread name is limited to 15 bytes I think - see for example [Is it possible to get `ps` to render thread names in wide mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/1782484/is-it-possible-to-get-ps-to-render-thread-names-in-wide-mode)

Comment: Oh you are right, thank you. That explains it. Maybe make it an answer? I assume that these names are so long then in the above example, because they just ported the code from windows.